# iPython: unicode in gnome-terminal (linux)

Tags: python, linux, unicode, ipython

[image]

Why is this happening in the gnome-terminal? I think it supports utf8, printing unicode shouldn't be a problem.

Also, I have these in the .bashrc

```
LANG="en_US.utf8"
LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL="en_US.utf8"

export LANG
export LANGUAGE
export LC_ALL
```

**Update:**

[image]
[image]

**Versions**

Python 2.7.1, IPython 0.10.1, Disto: Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: what happens if you use python instead of ipython?

Comment: also, what's the output of `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding` ?

Comment: It seems to be working in the normal python interpreter.

Comment: sys.stdout.encoding == 'UTF-8', same on python and ipython

Comment: Does the problem go away if you run `ipython -pylab` ?

Comment: ERROR: matplotlib could NOT be imported!, I have just the bare iPython, no numpy/scipy installed.

Comment: Try `ipython -gthread`, or `ipython -qthread`, `ipython -q4thread`, or `ipython -wthread`. With python 2.6.4, ipython 0.10, ubuntu 9.10 specifying any of these options seems to fix the problem, though I don't know why it should.

Comment: specifying ipython -[g|q|q4|w]thread paramaters doesnt solve the problem here.

Comment: the problem seems to be on ipython input (on a side note, ipython sucks).

Comment: Try sending through some characters like アイウエオ and see what happens. Part of your problem, at least for the first screenshot, seems to be that the font being used for output doesn't support all the characters that the system is trying to print (hence the boxes with numbers in them). Maybe see if you can change what the input encoding is on the python side? Does explicitly setting `sys.stdin.encoding` do anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPython 0.10 has a serious bug with Unicode. It's fixed in the development version, which will become 0.11, and we're hopefully releasing that in the next couple of weeks. If you're happy running a development version, you can get it [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython).